# LinkedList is returning empty

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I am doing the [LeetCode Problem 445](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers-ii/). The question is "You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The most significant digit comes first and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself." I tried solving it on my own by implementing two stacks and add the sum of numbers before the node as I pop from the stack. But, my output is returning empty list.

Example:

Input: (7 -> 2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
Output: 7 -> 8 -> 0 -> 7

Heres the code.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        s1 = []
        s2 = []

        #push all elements onto stack
        while l1!=None:
            s1.append(l1.val)
            l1 = l1.next

        while l2!=None:
            s2.append(l2.val)
            l2 = l2.next

        #create dummy node
        dummy = ListNode(0)
        l3 = dummy

        carry=0
        while len(s1)>0 or len(s2)>0:
            l1_value = l2_value = 0

            if len(s1)>0:
                l1_value = s1.pop()

            if len(s2)>0:
                l2_value = s2.pop()

            #do addition
            curr_sum = l1_value + l2_value + carry
            carry = curr_sum//10
            last_digit = curr_sum%10

            #add the new node to front of the linked list
            new_node = ListNode(last_digit)
            new_node.next = l3
            l3 = new_node

        if carry>0:
            new_node = ListNode(carry)
            head = ListNode(new_node)
            head.next = l3
            l3 = head

        return dummy.next
```

Comment: can you add some example with expected output

Comment: Your dummy node is at the end of list. dummy.next always return None.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using `dummy` variable just use `l3`

```
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        s1, s2 = [], []

        #push all elements onto stack
        while l1:
            s1.append(l1.val)
            l1 = l1.next

        while l2:
            s2.append(l2.val)
            l2 = l2.next

        l3, carry = None, 0
        while s1 or s2:
            l1_value = l2_value = 0

            if len(s1)>0:
                l1_value = s1.pop()

            if len(s2)>0:
                l2_value = s2.pop()

            #do addition
            curr_sum = l1_value + l2_value + carry
            carry, last_digit = divmod(curr_sum, 10)

            #add the new node to front of the linked list
            new_node = ListNode(last_digit)
            new_node.next = l3
            l3 = new_node

        if carry>0:
            head = ListNode(carry)
            head.next = l3
            l3 = head

        return l3
```